# web form creation drag and drop control the same as a WinForm?

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms

I have the need to create a custom contact form with textbox's drop down's and a push to submit button.  I've have an incredibility hard time designing the form like I need.  Is there a way to bring the drag and drop placement into a webform?

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302130.aspx

Comment: Have you tried just creating the form with Visual Studio?

Comment: Drag and drop with WebForms isn't a brilliant way to go, simply because it's difficult to ensure it looks correct in all browsers. You should really be using CSS to organise your front-end. I believe the drag-drop functionality uses `absolute` positioning which makes it quite restrictive in terms of handling different browsers and resolutions.

Comment: @John to be honest this really is my first go around with aspx, is there a good way to do it, i created an html table that hold this form specifically, i tried creating the labels and everything but it just looks like crap

Comment: The web presumes that you know something about HTML, pretty much. Sorry, but without at least a basic understanding, you're going to get crap results. The things that allow Windows Forms to do automatic layout that looks pretty good simply don't exist across browsers on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a ASPX page, there are 3 View options at the bottom of the page: Design, Split & Source. Simply use the Split view and drag/drop controls onto the page. With Split View you'll see the HTML that Visual Studio creates for you when you drop a control onto the page.

Dreamweaver is an ideal tool for this, its much quicker than VS.